# autopep8 not found in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, autopep8

If I try to use autopep8 in cygwin (64bit, WIndows10) i get the message "command not found".

```
$ autopep8
-bash: autopep8: command not found
```

I tried pip install autopep8 but pip is also not found, only pip2 and pip3.
If I use python -m pip install autopep8 it works so I can call

```
python -m autopep8
```

but I want to run a script where just autopep8 is called:

```
if ! type -p autopep8 >/dev/null; then
    echo "autopep8 not found" >&2
    autopep8() {
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: use an alias in you startup bash files. `alias autopep8=python -m autopep8`

Comment: @matzeri:i tried this before but the type -p check did not work

Comment: remove the `-p`

Answer (score 0):

First, you must install PyPi packages to the correct Python installation, and second, you must install the same package to every Python installation in which you want to use it.

Now, a special note about installing Python on Cygwin. You have a choice of several Python versions to install, and scores of packages for use with each of those versions. Avoid Python version 2 unless you have a clearly define reason, as it is post End-of-Life. Instead, install one of the versions of Python 3. As of today, version 3.6 and 3.7 have the more complete sets of optional packages. Version 3.8 beta 4 is available.

For a my install of Python 3.8, I used the Cygwin setup app to install these packages: Python38 (Py3K language interpreter), Python38-pip (Python package installation tool), Python38-setuptools (Python package management tool), Python38-virtualenv (Creates isolated Python environments), and Python38-wheel (Python package format module). To write X11 GUI apps, add Python38-tkinter (Py3K Tkinter GUI module). To install binary packages, add Python38-devel (Py3K language interpreter).

You will be able to install pure Python packages from PyPI. To install binary packages you will also need to have the GNU compiler tool chain installed, and you will need to handle dependencies with other Cygwin packages on your own.

The Python 3.6 and 3.7 installations have addition packages which, in many cases, contain binary packages with the above mentioned dependencies already resolved, or have some useful customizations for the Cygwin environment.

Cygwin has both Python 2 and Python 3. As of today, after installation, you execute Python 2 by `python` and Python 3 by `python3`. Be careful which Python you execute as you may get a windows version of Python, if installed, and in your path. `which python` will always tell where the executable lives, and `python -V`, etc., will tell you which version you are running. Generally, you want to run a Cygwin version of Python from the bash prompt and Windows versions of Python only from the command prompt or windows GUI.

The safest way to use pip is to use the module version for the Python executable you have chosen, i.e., `python -m pip`, etc. This avoids having to also remember to use pip with Python and pip3 with Python3.